# removing variable string on many files

Tags: text-processing, text-formatting, bioinformatics

I have many files that contain similar strings as:

```
>33100_Pseudomonas_etcetera1
texttexttext
>33632_Pseudomonas_etcetera2
texttexttext
>36406_Pseudomonas_etcetera3
texttexttext
```

and I need outputs like this:

```
>Pseudomomas_etcetera1
texttexttext
>Pseudomomas_etcetera2
texttexttext
>Pseudomomas_etcetera3
texttexttext
```

Pretty sure there is a simple sed solution which I can't seem to figure out

Notes: The characters are always five numbers followed by an underscore followed by Pseudomonas_etcetera. This string is always at the beginning of its line and it always starts with ">". All files have a ".sorted" extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`sed`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) does it:

```
sed -E 's/>([0-9]+_)(\w+)/>\2/' files
```

if your pattern exactly in question:

```
sed -E 's/([0-9]+_)//' files
```

- `-E` use extended regular expressions
- `([0-9]+_)(\w+)` defines two *Word Pattern* region which you would access them with *\1* and *\2*.

Comment: Note that if the header looks like `>098_thing more things here`, then the trailing words would be removed by the first `sed` command. The second `sed` command would remove digits followed by an underscore _anywhere_ in the file.

Answer (score 1):

Using standard `sed`, and assuming all files are located in the current directory:

```
mkdir fixed || exit 1   # exits if the output directory already exists
for filename in *.sorted; do
    sed '/^>[0-9]*_/s//>/' "$filename" >"fixed/$filename"
done
```

This will iterate over all filenames matching the pattern `*.sorted`, and for each one run a short `sed` script.

The `sed` script will locate all Fasta headers that start with a number followed by a underscore. When it find one, it will replace the header marker, the number and the underscore with just the `>` header marker.

The result will be written to new files in the `fixed` subdirectory.

Answer (score 1):

> [***OP wrote***] Pretty sure there is a simple sed solution which I can't seem to figure out.

That is correct.

> [***OP wrote***] Notes: The characters are always five numbers followed by an underscore followed by Pseudomonas_etcetera. This string is always at the beginning of its line and it always starts with ">". All files have a ".sorted" extension.

Your description of the pbm statement is pretty exact, in  the sense that it can be gainfully translated into `sed` code. Here's how:

- This string is always at the beginning of its line and it always starts with ">":   regex => `/^>/`
- The characters are always 5 numeric characters:   regex => `/^>[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/`
- Followed by an underscore followed by "Pseudomonas_etcetera":   regex => `/^>[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_Pseudomonas_etcetera/`
- The basic syntax of the substitute command in `sed` is: `s/regex/rpl_str/`, meaning whatever portion of the pattern space (normally the current line, aka, record) is matched by the regex (on the `LHS` of the `s///` command, is to be substituted with the replacement string on the `RHS` of the `s///` command.
- So your command to do the substitution is:
- `sed -e 's/^>[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_Pseudomonas_etcetera/>Pseudomonas_etcetera/' inp1.sorted`
- Disclaimer: Not tested it.